# Coloring of anchor tag on click of submit button

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am building online exam system, test page is built using php and jquery. Questions are coming from different page using jquery ajax method and for every test there is a temporary test table which is deleted after every test, this table stores current test's question id and response marked by the student. What I am doing or want to do is when the user clicks on submit button this question is marked as done on the left side bar which contains all the questions.

I am doing this by checking the temporary table and fetching the question id from that table and marking it colored using jquery, it is working fine for some questions and skipping some(some gets colored but some are not)randomly.
Can someone help me with this?

Here's my jquery code to fetch question id

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    $.post( "getquesupdate.php", function( data ) {
        $("#q"+data).addClass("doneques");
    });
});
```

and this my getquesupdate page code

```
<?php
    session_start();
   include("includes/conn.php");

        $table_name = $_SESSION['table_name'];

        $sql = "SELECT qid FROM `$table_name` ";

        $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

     if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {    
        while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC) )
        {
            $id =  $row['qid'];
        }

    }

    echo $id;

?>
```

Screenshot of the test page

[image]

Comment: How do you build the table with questions 1 to 15?

Comment: Your PHP code doesn't appear to receive the question ID, so how is it supposed to know what to return? Is there only one record in the table?

Comment: I need not have to pass question id to getquesupdate it is selecting all records from the temporary table and will only return the last question id as echo is outside of while loop, so whenever submit is clicked question id and response is submitted to temporary table and getquesupdate page will return only the last question id that is the latest question id from the table

Comment: @Adder Questions are in questions table and I am fetching them from that table.

Comment: I believe those you've 2 kind of buttons on your page. First, one kind button which on left-hand side & second kind of buttons which probably exist somewhere understand the questions, which is not visible in the given image. Am I right?

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT qid FROM `$table_name` ORDER BY qid ASC";` would be more reliable way to get the qid.

Comment: @Adder questions are random, order by will work for them? I want to fetch the record which is latest in the table.

Comment: @mi6crazyheart I didn't get what you are trying to ask?

Comment: You should add a timestamp column to the table then and order by that. You can use NOW() as value for the column when inserting it, Because there is no rule that says mysql has to return rows by insert order, if it works it is luck.

Comment: @programmingArrow why don't you do something like on click of LEFT SIDE button get the ID of the button then shows respective questions in the right-hand side. Then, when user will click any Submit button then make an ajax call to the server side for saving the response of user & return back an appropriate response to the client side. Then, by checking the response & button ID(which you've already got ) you can change the Color of the button.